# `base` tag causes iframe to open as new window in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a problem with the [`base` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) which only affects Internet Explorer (versions 8, 9 and 10).

The following code is used to open dynamic content in an iframe and it functions correctly in Chrome and Firefox. It also functions correctly in Internet Explorer, but only without the `<base target="_blank"/>` tag. The inclusion of this tag causes the iframe to open as a new window (which makes sense, however this is not what I am trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <base target="_blank"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load_iframe(name, height, width) {
                var div = document.getElementById(name);

                var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
                ifrm.id = 'iframe_' + name;
                ifrm.frameBorder = 0;
                ifrm.scrolling = 'no';
                ifrm.noresize = 'noresize';
                ifrm.marginheight = 0;
                ifrm.marginwidth = 0;
                if (height !== 0) {
                    ifrm.height = height;
                }
                if (width !== 0) {
                    ifrm.width = width;
                }
                div.appendChild(ifrm);

                content = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head></head><body></body></html>';

                if (/msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) || window.opera) {
                    ifrm.contentWindow.contents = content;
                    return ifrm.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
                } else {
                    doc = ifrm.contentDocument;
                    doc.open();
                    doc.write(content);
                    doc.close();
                    return ifrm;
                }
            }

            load_iframe('main', 250, 300);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this issue? Unfortunately, I couldn't get the code to work in a fiddle, perhaps because it relies on `<base/>` being in the `<head>`.

Comment: Have you tried giving the iframe a "target" attribute with the value "_self"?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I don't think `target` is a valid attribute for an iframe

Comment: `div = document.getElementById(div);` and `ifrm.id = 'iframe_' + div;` doesn't make sense, `div` here is a HTMLElement, not a string. Also `iframe`s don't have `noresize` property, it's for `frame`s.

Comment: Whoops yep, I have fixed the `div` variable, which was wrong.

Comment: What exact issue are you getting in IE 8/9/10. I've tested it and it appears works fine without the base element.

Comment: @Fresh the issue only shows up _with_ the base element. It's written in the question.

Comment: @JoshuaSpence if you remove the base tag, the iframe works correctly in Chrome and IE10/9/8. The purpose of "target=_blank" is to open the link in a new window/tab, so if you dont want this dont include it.

Comment: @Fresh: But an `iframe` is not a link... it's a frame.

Answer (score 4):

I just removed the `/msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) ||` part, and works fine on IE8. Are you sure that you need this piece of code?

However, whether you don't want remove this piece, you can remove the `base` tag and add it **after** you create the `iframe`:

```
load_iframe('main', 250, 300);
//and then:
var hd = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var bs = document.createElement("base");
bs.target= "_blank";
hd.appendChild(bs);
```

I tested on chrome, IE8, IE11 and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments target="_blank" makes the browser open a new window or tab (depends on your configuration).

Just remove it or replace by self (tested on IE8):

```
<base target="_self"/>
```