# Iframe opening in New window in IE8 and 9

Tags: html, wordpress

I am Using below code which working fine on Mozilla and chrome. But IE open NEw Window..
I have also applied a  in Head Tage For Compatible.

```
<iframe name="iframeone" src="http://tsprojects.net/demo/ui-dev/wildernesslighting/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Comp-5.mp4" width="120" height="120" id="iframeone" ></iframe>
```

Comment: hi see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318578/base-tag-causes-iframe-to-open-as-new-window-in-internet-explorer